# Value do h:selectOneMenu não está sendo definido

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee

Já criei formulários em JSF várias vezes, mas não estou entendendo o por quê do `value` desse `selectOneMenu` não estar sendo definido ("setado").

```
        <h:form>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="nova-matriz-select"
                                 value="#{historicoMatrizMatriculaBean.novaMatrizCurricular}"
                                 required="true"
                                 styleClass="uniformselect">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Selecione --" noSelectionOption="true" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{historicoMatrizMatriculaBean.matrizesCurriculares}"
                                       var="mc" itemValue="#{mc}" itemLabel="#{mc.opcaoCurricular.complementoSigla} - #{mc.nome}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>

                <h:commandButton id="salvar-btn"
                                 action="list.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"
                                 actionListener="#{historicoMatrizMatriculaBean.salvarAlteracao()}"
                                 value="Salvar"
                                 styleClass="stdbtn btn_orange submitbtn" />
        </h:form>
```

Alguém consegue enxergar o problema aqui?

OBS: Os getters/setters do atributo `novaMatrizCurricular` foram criados.

---

EDITADO

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class HistoricoMatrizMatriculaBean {

    private MatrizCurricular novaMatrizCurricular;
    private List<MatrizCurricular> matrizesCurriculares;

    public void init() {
        this.matrizesCurriculares = service.obterMatrizes();
    }

    public List<MatrizCurricular> getMatrizesCurriculares() {
        return matrizesCurriculares;
    }

    public void setMatrizesCurriculares(List<MatrizCurricular> matrizesCurriculares) {
        this.matrizesCurriculares = matrizesCurriculares;
    }

    public MatrizCurricular getNovaMatrizCurricular() {
        return novaMatrizCurricular;
    }

    public void setNovaMatrizCurricular(MatrizCurricular novaMatrizCurricular) {
        this.novaMatrizCurricular = novaMatrizCurricular;
    }
}
```

Comment: Poste o código do ManagedBean para ajudar a análise

Comment: Adicionei o que achei mais pertinente do ManagedBean @Marquezani...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tenho certeza absoluta sobre a causa do problema, mas suspeito que seja por conta da implementação do método `hasCode()` ou do método `toString()` da classe `MatrizCurricular`. Ambos os métodos tem implementações bem diferentes de outras classes do mesmo projeto.

Como uma alteração nesses métodos pode causar impactos não previstos, utilizei um conversor do projeto OmniFaces: `SelectItemsIndexConverter` → http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsIndexConverter